# How to express with Progress Indicator when calculating?

Tags: cdf-format

I'm going to create a Manipulate that outputs Factor [x^n-1] when I type n in InputField and click the Update button. Importantly, I'm going to Cloud Publish this one!!

```
Manipulate[ 
tf = True; 
out = Short[Factor[x^n - 1],10]; 
tf = False;  
Dynamic@If[tf, Dynamic@ProgressIndicator[Appearance -> "Indeterminate"], out], 
{n, 2000}, 
{tf, True, ControlType -> None}, 
AppearanceElements -> None, ContinuousAction -> None ]
```

If the input n value increases, the calculation time takes a long time. I want to express it as a Progress Indicator while the result is being output (ex.n=3000)

How to express with Progress Indicator when calculating?